# Granting permission to the Python installation folder on Linux

Tags: linux, anaconda

I originally installed Python with Anaconda on our 16.10 Ubuntu server, and I have packages installed in a certain environment I made with conda.

```
/home/username/anaconda3/envs/my_env
```

I want to give my coworker the ability to run scripts with Python on this server (specifically with Jupyterhub). How do I grant him permission to utilize this environment?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming, server management is outside the scope of SO.

Comment: I suppose your envs have a group and you want a new user beeing in this group workers. you can : useradd -G group-name newusername

Comment: Hi, no. There are no groups at all. I have been the only user of this machine ever since it was created so I never set anything up for multiple users. Yesterday was the first time I used adduser, but I never created a group for us.

Comment: you need to create a group set usernames and services look at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/ example with ftp services, may be you have to add some futures in the bashrc and export environment variables to specific group ...